# Show lable/text if the combo box contains only a single value

Tags: winforms, combobox, dynamic-list

I have a combo box that contains a dynamic list of values.

I would like to do this:

if there is only single value - the combo box will be displayed as text only (maybe: will be replaced with a "label" or something similar) and will not give any choice but will only display.

What is the easiest and most convenient way to implement this?

Thank you

Comment: You could set the `DropDownStyle` of your ComboBox to `Simple` and pre-select the only item, so it looks like a Textbox; when the DataSource changes or you add Items, set its `DropDownStyle` to `DropDownList`

Comment: Or set `DropDownStyle` to `DropDown`, just based on how the Control should *look like*.

Comment: but I dont like that it's look like text (with option to change it). I would like it will be like lable. Thank you!

Comment: Well, you can send `EM_SETREADONLY` to the Edit Control of your ComboBox, so its Text cannot be changed. Maybe complement with `TabStop = false`, handle Enter / MouseEnter etc. (better handled with a Custom Control that filters System messages) -- You *could* build a UserControl that toggles the visibility of a ComboBox / Label based on the number of Items, but it may become hard to handle when the Dpi value changes or the User scales the Font or the Screen, so using a single control that has the same behavior when these conditions change can be less prone to layout mistakes.